# Multilingual views hide if no translation

Tags: views, 8, i18n-l10n

My Drupal website has 2 languages and I created **blog view** that lists articles (content type). Default language is English.

Problem is that some articles are only in German and then on my English view I get German articles.

I tried adding **Content: Translation language** Filter that I set to **Interface text language selected for page** but then on German page I only get articles that were created on German and the ones that were created in English but have German translation are missing.

Query :

```
SELECT node_field_data.created AS node_field_data_created, 
node_field_data.nid AS nid
FROM 
{node_field_data} node_field_data
LEFT JOIN {node__field_content_type} node__field_content_type ON 
node_field_data.nid = node__field_content_type.entity_id AND 
(node__field_content_type.deleted = '0' AND 
node__field_content_type.langcode = node_field_data.langcode)
WHERE (( (node_field_data.status = '1') AND (node_field_data.type IN  
('article')) AND (node__field_content_type.field_content_type_value = '1') 
))
ORDER BY node_field_data_created DESC
LIMIT 5 OFFSET 0
```

Query with **Translation language** filter:

```
SELECT node_field_data.created AS node_field_data_created, 
node_field_data.nid AS nid
FROM 
{node_field_data} node_field_data
LEFT JOIN {node__field_content_type} node__field_content_type ON 
node_field_data.nid = node__field_content_type.entity_id AND 
(node__field_content_type.deleted = '0' AND 
node__field_content_type.langcode = node_field_data.langcode)
LEFT JOIN {node__field_tags} node__field_tags ON node_field_data.nid = 
node__field_tags.entity_id AND node__field_tags.field_tags_target_id = '4'
WHERE (( (node__field_tags.field_tags_target_id IS NULL) )AND(( 
(node_field_data.status = '1') AND (node_field_data.type IN  ('article')) 
AND (node__field_content_type.field_content_type_value = '1') AND 
(node_field_data.langcode IN  ('en')) )))
ORDER BY node_field_data_created DESC
LIMIT 5 OFFSET 0
```

From queries, I see that LEFT JOIN is adding **node__field_content_type.langcode = node_field_data.langcode** and I think that is making problems when I add the language filter, any suggestion?

Comment: The LEFT JOIN is OK, it joins the entries with the same language in both tables. But your query is filtering english: `(node_field_data.langcode IN  ('en', 'en')) )))`, so by looking at the filter this means the interface language is detected as english.

Comment: @4k4 still does not explain why I do not get translations only `original language` when I add filter

Comment: The node_field_data table contains all languages, it doesn't matter whether this is the original or translated version. There was no more information for me to debug this any further. My idea was to get you away from debugging the LEFT JOIN, because this joins only one bundle field to the main node data table, and pointing you at the filter in the query and the language detection. What have you configured there? (admin/config/regional/language/detection)

Comment: Maybe I'm on the wrong track, did think that the error is the English filter on a German page. The join could be the problem, if the field `field_content_type` in your node is not translatable, see this issue https://www.drupal.org/node/2451657

Comment: @4k4 `node__field_content_type.langcode` has only original language while `node_field_data.langcode` has all languages, that is why I thought that that will make a problem. Detection http://prntscr.com/f9k62p, will check that issue. Thank you

Comment: @4k4 you were right, that `field_content_type` is not translatable and when I removed it everything was working, thank you again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I was doing condition in views with field that wasn't translatable and views are adding join on `langcode`, thanks to user [4k4](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/47547/4k4) that linked to this issue that can be found [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/2451657).

I fixed this by removing untranslated field from view and hooking into `hook_views_query_alter` and adding relationship myself :

```
<?php

use Drupal\views\ViewExecutable;
use Drupal\views\Plugin\views\query\QueryPluginBase;

function hook_views_query_alter(ViewExecutable $view, 
QueryPluginBase $query)
{
    if ($view->id() == 'blog') {
        $definition = [
            'table' => 'node__field_content_type',
            'field' => 'entity_id',
            'left_table' => 'node_field_data',
            'left_field' => 'nid',
        ];
        $join = Drupal::service('plugin.manager.views.join')->createInstance('standard', $definition);
        $query->addRelationship('node__field_content_type', $join, 'node__field_content_type');
        $query->addWhere('1', 'node__field_content_type.field_content_type_value', 1, '=');
    }
}
```

Also this hook has to be in `MODULE.views_execution.inc` file

Comment: Thank you for sharing the solution with us. I am not sure where you add this part of code, a file `MY_MODULE.views_execution.inc` has no impact in my environment.
For me it worked to add it to my `MY_MODULE.module`-file as the `function MY_MODULE_views_query_alter(ViewExe...`.

Comment: @btemperli maybe something changed since I needed this, I didn't work with drupal for over a year now